# Destroying SecretKey throws DestroyFailedException?

Tags: java, java-8

I am writing a function to generate secret key (bytes) based on a password using SecretKeyFactory. I want to destroy SecretKey instance when it is not needed anymore But it throws an exception.

```
try {
    byte[] salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");

    PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec("password".toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 256);

    SecretKey secretkey = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    byte[] key = secretkey.getEncoded();

    // Using key

    // Destroy key
    Arrays.fill(key, (byte)0);

    // Destroy secretKey
    secretkey.destroy();  // --> Throw DestroyFailedException

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am using Oracle JDK1.8.0_66 on Mac.

I take a look at SecretKey source code and I found this default implementation (SecretKey implements Destroyable interface)

```
public default void destroy() throws DestroyFailedException {
    throw new DestroyFailedException();
}
```

It means: the implementation of SecretKey does not override the destroy method to destroy internal password chars and internal key bytes.

Is this a bug in JDK 8?

Comment: According to the Java 8 API for SecretKey [its only two known implementing classes are KerberosKey and SecretKeySpec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKey.html). Of those two only KerberosKey overrides destroy(). The documentation of secret key also says any extending classes should override the destroy() method provided by Destroyable, so this doesn't look like a bug but intended behavior. Do you know the actual class being returned by your generateSecret call?

Comment: @BrandonDockery: The implementation is com.sun.crypto.provider.PBKDF2KeyImpl. This class implements PBEKey interface that inherits from SercretKey interface.

Comment: Remember you should also call keySpec.clearPassword()  (although this doesn't resolve the lack of clearing the SecretKey)

Comment: @BrandonDockery Late comment: I think it is an API bug as you currently cannot program your code to call `destroy` and there doesn't seem to be any way to test if an object is destroyable. Maybe they should have created a method `tryDestroy(): DestructionResult` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct. The [PBKDF2KeyImpl](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mullan/webrevs/ascarpin/8001596/webrev.02/src/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/PBKDF2KeyImpl.java.html) class does not implement the destroy method inherited from Destroyable. [It also looks like you are not the first person to be concerned by this](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/security-dev/2015-May/012222.html).

This is not necessarily a bug in the JDK as such, since the API for [SecretKey](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKey.html) explicitly leaves it up to the implementing classes to define this behavior, though it does seem a little odd that this behavior is not overridden.

Comment: No problem, but if this answers your question could you mark it as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This looks pretty bad to me. I am also looking for ways to destroy a SecretKey. You can use reflection. I know it is super hacky, but it allows us to get the underlying private key array:

```
public class DestroyableSecretKeySpec extends SecretKeySpec {
    public DestroyableSecretKeySpec( byte[] key, int offset, int len, String algorithm ) {
        super( key, offset, len, algorithm );
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            // Use hacky reflection to clear the underlying private key from memory.
            // This is so ugly :/
            Field f = SecretKeySpec.class.getDeclaredField( "key" );
            f.setAccessible(true);
            byte[] key = (byte[]) f.get( this );
            Arrays.fill( key, (byte)0xCC );
        } catch( NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e ) {
            throw new EncryptionException( "Can't use reflection to clear a secret key.", e );
        }
    }
}
```